# Got an error when using load_img in tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've installed tensorflow_cpu in my virtual environment.

When I imported some tensorflow packages, like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
```

it seemed like everything is fine and I got no error, but when I used load_img to load one of image from my computer:

```
picture = load_img('cahir.png', target_size=(224, 224))
picture = img_to_array(picture)
img = picture/255
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
```

I got this error, seemed like tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image isn't working..

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10668/528885050.py in <module>
----> 1 picture = load_img('cahir.png', target_size=(224, 224))
      2 picture = img_to_array(picture)
      3 img = picture/255
      4 img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

~\anaconda3\envs\tf_cpu\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    311       ValueError: if interpolation method is not supported.
    312   """
--> 313   return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,
    314                         target_size=target_size, interpolation=interpolation)
    315 

~\anaconda3\envs\tf_cpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    109         color_mode = 'grayscale'
    110     if pil_image is None:
--> 111         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
    113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:

ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

Comment: Did you try installing the PIL dependency? `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

(As paraphrased by AloneTogether)

With the error, it shows you need to install `Pillow` and `import PIL` library in your system to `import` and `load` images.

```
pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image
```

You can check more details on  [PIL(Python Imaging Library)](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/) to install here.